# How to get a value from a promise in EmberJS with custom Adapter

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am pretty new to EmberJS, I am trying to get back a value from a promise given by a custom adapter since the backend is not rails API compliant

Here is my custom adapter:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

    export default DS.Adapter.extend({
      findRecord( store, type, id ) {
        return Ember.$.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/user/by-username/" + id );

  }
});
```

I also modified my serializer:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey:'alias',
});
```

my controller looks like this (where I am stuck):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  username:'',
  actions: {
    searchUser : function(){
      var id = this.get('username');
      var promise = this.get('store').findRecord('roles', id);
      var self = this
      promise.then(function(value) {
        self.set('username', value.get('ID'));
      }, function(reason) {
        // on rejection
      });


    }
  }
});
```

Specifically on this line from above controller, I can not get it to work:

```
self.set('username', value.get('ID'));
```

The ajax is exectued succesfully since I can see it happen on chrome dev tools returning json following data:

```
{"ID":"73ebf44f-71bf-4b60-a755-a4bbef208ef1","mjID":34049137,"alias":"coderman","registration_date":"2017-07-07T20:03:11Z"}
```

I am not able to get the ID value to be set to the username property

Answer (score 0):

Your server should response with expected JSON data format. refer [ember-data-model-maker](http://andycrum.github.io/ember-data-model-maker/) for sample.

Sample format,

```
{
"data": {
"type": "roles",
"id": "1",
"attributes": {
"id": "foo",
"mj-id": "foo",
"alias": "foo",
"registration-date": "foo" },
}
}
```

Note :
1.Look at the `mj-id` and `registration-date` it's hyphenated. and you model property name should like `mjId` and `registrationDate`.
2. `findRecord` we need to mention model name `role` not the `roles`